# How can i open different URLs (in a web browser) under different conditions in C?

Tags: c, function, url

For example, I want to have the program get a name/userID from the user and open the corresponding profile, on a particular website.

i.e-

Name: "Steve".

URL: "www.website.profile/steve"

Name: "Bob"

URL: "www.website.profile/bob"

I can open an URL using: 
`system ("start www.website.com");`

But how do I make this dynamic, so it can open a URL that depends on user input?

Comment: Consider the following prototypes: `int main(int argc, char* * argv);` and `int scanf(const char *format, ...);` or `FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode)`. That makes for about all input types...

Comment: Yes, but how do i use this to open a URL, in a web browser? What function do i call to open the browser and go to a URL, that changes depending on user input?

Comment: You already know of `int system(const char *command);`, so I can't see what is blocking you...

Comment: Yes, like i said, i know how to open a single URL. But i can't implement this to opening a URL that will change under a given condition.

Comment: I am sorry, I find your question very unclear, could you provide a concrete execution example?

Comment: I tried passing a pointer to the string holding the name, but it doesn't work. I'm a noob, can you please at least tell me what the system function call would look like?

Answer (score 0):

Could try some pseudo-code like this...

```
wchar_t OutputString[100];
wchar_t Name[25];
strcpy(Name,"Joe"); // simulating Joe entering his name
printf(OutputString,"start www.website.profile/%s",Name);
system(OutputString);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a simplistic approach:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char buffer[100];
    sprintf(buffer, "start www.website.com/%s", argv[1]);
    system(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

it uses the first argument passed